# VST on Elementary

Tags: software-installation, audio

I spent researching and trying this for about a whole day. I have some windows VST such as Softube, BIAS FX and Surfer EQ that I'd like to use with Reaper (running on WINE). There were some different apps that promised to run windows VST but I could not make any of them work. I must say I'm newbie in Linux and using terminal but I tried my best. If someone could walk me through how to make these VSTs work I'd be so greatful!

Comment: The question is about a piece of third party software, and is therefore not suitable for a question site about elementary OS.

Answer (score 1):

this is a very specific question, and you should really direct it to Reaper / Wine / Linux music production forums instead. To get you started though, there is a similar question, with some suggestions that should work:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1375751

I also read that a Native Linux port of Reaper has been created and might also help solve your problems:

https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/phoronix/general-discussion/868977-native-linux-build-of-the-digital-audio-workstation-reaper-5-20-beta-10-available